# How to make a php subpage in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Let's see if I can make my question clear. I have a wordpress website that has a page labeled "game". I have it set up so that page is made out of php rather than the wordpress editor. What I can't figure out is how do I create separate subpages within this one page. 
So what I have is

rheanna.net/game

and what I want is

rheanna.net/game?page1, rheanna.net/game?page2, etc...

Here is what I've managed to code so far, but what I get is rheanna.net/game/?AA001 and it continues to show the first section and not the "elseif" section that I want it to show.

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$requested = $_GET['p']; 
if($requested == ""){ 
    /**
     * @example Safe usage: $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
     * if ( !($current_user instanceof WP_User) )
     *     return;
     */
    echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . '<br />';
    echo 'User email: ' . $current_user->user_email . '<br />';
    echo 'User first name: ' . $current_user->user_firstname . '<br />';
    echo 'User last name: ' . $current_user->user_lastname . '<br />';
    echo 'User display name: ' . $current_user->display_name . '<br />';
    echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID . '<br />';
    ?><br><a href="?AA001">Choice 1</a>
    <?php
}
elseif($requested == "AA001"){ 
$user_id = $current_user->ID;
$game = "AA001";
if(update_user_meta( $user_id, 'game', $game)) {
    echo "Success!";
}
}
```

I hope what I'm trying to achieve here is clear, but please ask questions if I wasn't thorough enough.

EDIT:
I finally figured it out! In case this helps someone else, here you go!

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$requested = $_GET['page']; 
if(!$requested){ 
    /**
     * @example Safe usage: $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
     * if ( !($current_user instanceof WP_User) )
     *     return;
     */
    echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . '<br />';
    echo 'User email: ' . $current_user->user_email . '<br />';
    echo 'User first name: ' . $current_user->user_firstname . '<br />';
    echo 'User last name: ' . $current_user->user_lastname . '<br />';
    echo 'User display name: ' . $current_user->display_name . '<br />';
    echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID . '<br />';
    ?><br><a href="?page=AA001">Choice 1</a>
    <?php
}
elseif($requested == "AA001"){ 
$user_id = $current_user->ID;
$game = "AA001";
if(update_user_meta( $user_id, 'game', $game)) {
    echo "Success!";
}
}
```

Comment: I probably understood you wrong, but I'll try and steer you in the right direction. You can create a post, or a custom post type, that can be displayed on /game, and also you can access a single post via/game?page1, or whatever you decide to set your permalinks to. That would be the easiest way to go about things. This way, you are able to have one page - /game, that displays all the "subpages", or posts, and you have the option to click on one that takes you to, say /game?page1 and displays just that "subpage" /post.

Comment: I was trying to avoid setting up wordpress pages and trying to put multiple "pages" in the php file - which I've now been told is an anchor link?? I'm still kinda lost...

Comment: Either use wordpress, or don't. Don't go down the middle, as that is no-man's land

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure I'm going to go down the middle. After hours of fiddling I finally got what I was going for!! (updating original post)